# Duplicate elimination assignment

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

I am currently enrolling in a beginning C# programming class online. It's hard to contact my teacher for help and I am struggling with this current program I am very close but my solution must match 100% to the teacher's solution.
I have to move the error message before the list current efforts lead with no success. Please help I know this may be a silly mistake but I'm still a beginner.
my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace midterm
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int size;
        Console.WriteLine("How many numbers will you enter?");
        size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] numbers = new int[size];
        int count = 0;

        while (count < size)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter number: ");
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (number >= 10 && number <= 100)
            {
                bool containsNumber = false;


                for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
                {
                    if (number == numbers[j])
                        containsNumber = true;


                    if (numbers[j] > 0)
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", numbers[j]);
                }

                if (!containsNumber)
                {
                    if (count < numbers.Length)
                        numbers[count] = number;
                    Console.WriteLine(number);
                }
                 else
                {
                   Console.WriteLine("{0} has already been entered", number);
               }
                ++count;
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("number must be between 10 and 100");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

test case:

```
10
90
50
90
22
18
65
22
92
100
20
```

correct solution:

```
How many numbers will you enter? 
Enter number: 90 
Enter number: 90 
50 
Enter number: 90 has already been entered
90
50
Enter number: 90
50
22
Enter number: 90
50
22
18
Enter number: 90
50
22
18
65
Enter number: 22 has already been entered
90
50
22
18
65
Enter number: 90
50
22
18
65
92
Enter number: 90
50
22
18
65
92
100
Enter number: 90
50
22
18
65
92
100
20
```

my solution:

```
How many numbers will you enter?
Enter number: 90
Enter number: 90
50
Enter number: 90
50

90 has already been entered
Enter number: 90
50
22
Enter number: 90
50
22
18
Enter number: 90
50
22
18
65
Enter number: 90
50
22
18
65

22 has already been entered
Enter number: 90
50
22
18
65
92
Enter number: 90
50
22
18
65
92
100
Enter number: 90
50
22
18
65
92
100
20
```

Comment: What kind of help you are looking for? Hint on how to debug code?

Comment: Have you learned about List<T> or Linq? If so, there are simpler solutions and what version of C#?

Comment: You know, stack isn't a code writing service...you need to ask something specific or you aren't going to get any answers!

Comment: All I need to do is move the error message "number has already been entered" to appear before the list instead of after.

Comment: I see - note that 90% of text in your post is *not* related to problem you trying to solve (like "talk to teacher", "new in C#",... and a lot of text in sample data) - if you skip all that text it would be easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are going to have to move/duplicate your for loop:

```
if (number >= 10 && number <= 100)
{
   bool containsNumber = false;

   for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
   {
       if (number == numbers[j])
            containsNumber = true;
   }

   if (!containsNumber)
   {
      if (count < numbers.Length)
            numbers[count] = number;
      Console.WriteLine(number);
   }
   else
   {
       Console.WriteLine("{0} has already been entered", number);
   }
   for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
   {
       if (numbers[j] > 0)
          Console.WriteLine("{0}", numbers[j]);
   }
   ++count;
```

Basically, you need to do your check before you print the list, but the only way to know if the number has been entered is to iterate through the list. Thus, you must iterate through the list again to do the print after checking for a duplicate.

Even using IEnumerable.Contains (which is the Linq suggestion) will do this, but it will do it a bit more performantly and hides the ugly extra for loop.

Let me know if you have any questions!